# Why am I getting Segmentation fault 11 (reading inputs using fgets and storing in array)?

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, fault

Sorry if this is a very noob question, I am a beginner to C and am having significant trouble understand pointers and other concepts making it very difficult. Getting segmentation fault, I don't know why please help. I think it may be from the use of arrays to store. Also, if you could recommend a debugger would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 #include <string.h>


char *lineaccept(char *buf, size_t sz){ //Getting inputs using fgets() and storing it in buf.
        if(fgets(buf,sz,stdin)==NULL){
            printf("ERROR\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        if(strlen(buf) == 1) {
                printf("ERROR\n");
                return NULL;
        }
        return buf;
        }


void delimitLine(char *buf, char *delimited[], size_t max){ //Taking the string from buf and getting each individual word to store in split[]

if(buf != NULL){
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(buf, s);
    int counter = 0;
    while( token != NULL && counter <= max){
        split[counter] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, s); 
        counter ++;
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < counter; y++){
        if(split[y]==NULL){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("%s\n",split[y]);
        }
    }
}

}

int main(void) {
    const int maxWords = 10;
    char maxLenInput[11];
    char *arrOfWords[100];
    char inputFromLine[100];
    while(strcmp((strcpy(inputFromLine,lineaccept(maxLenInput, maxWords))), "")>0) {
        delimitline(inputFromLine, arrOfWords, maxWords);
    }


     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and it'll tell you where in your code it is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following part of your code will return `NULL` if you press solely Enter in the console (without having typed any other character before the "Enter"). This is because `fgets` will store the new line as the only character in `buf`, such that `strlen(buf)` will be `1` then:

```
char *read_line(char *buf, size_t sz){
   .... 
   if (fgets(buf,sz,stdin)) {
      if(strlen(buf) == 1) {
         return NULL;
         ...
```

When you then pass the result of a call to `read_line` to `strcpy`, as you do with

```
strcpy(inputFromLine,read_line(maxLenInput, maxWords)
```

then you actually pass `NULL` to `strcpy` and access "invalid" memory thereby; undefined behaviour, likely a segfault.